# Convert byte[] to short[] such that each short element contains 13 bits of data

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

So I am working on a solution where I need any given data type to be broken into a 13 bit encoding I am able to work with everything else except string.

So Steps as I look to code this.

Convert String to byte array

Collect first byte in a short with bit shift of byte to 13

Bit shift next byte with 5 and or it with short to get first short

This is getting cumbersome to iterate I think the approach is all wrong. Can I get a possible solution?

Comment: Can you describe what you want a little more clearly? As I read it, you want to break up an arbitrary amount of data into 13-bit pieces and store each piece in a `short`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JavaCoder Do you want to write this algorithm yourself as an exercise or are you happy with using an existing library that can do it?

Comment: If you can direct me to a open source library that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BigInteger`.  Initialize it with the `byte[]`.  While it's not zero, mask out 13 bits with the `and()` method and convert to a short via `intValue()`.  Shift it 13 bits to the right with `shiftRight()` and repeat.

Comment: Very creative! Shifting the BigIntegers might be a bit slow though if they get really large.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenLR](http://www.openlr.org/) has a binary library available [here.](http://www.openlr.org/download.html)

It has a `ByteArrayBitstreamInput` class that takes a `byte[]` parameter in its constructor, you can then get an arbitrary number of bits out with `getInt()` and cast that into a `short`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is lightly tested.  It is a low level solution, but it won't have much overhead (like shifting the entire input or garbage generation or library bloat).

```
// Length of shorts array must be at least (8 * bytes.length + 12) / 13.
static void convert(byte[] bytes, short[] shorts) {
    int nBitsAvail = 13;
    int i = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        if (nBitsAvail >= 8) {
            // Entire byte fits in available space in short.
            shorts[i] = (short) ((shorts[i] << 8) | b);
            nBitsAvail -= 8;
        } else {
            // Byte must be split between bits remaining in this short and the next.
            int nBitsNeeded = 8 - nBitsAvail ;
            shorts[i] = (short) ((shorts[i] << nBitsAvail) | (b >> nBitsNeeded));
            shorts[++i] = (short) (b & (0xff >> nBitsAvail));
            nBitsAvail = 13 - nBitsNeeded;
        }
    }
    shorts[i] <<= nBitsAvail;
}
```